# Copy files from one folder to another based on similar file name

Tags: perl, batch-file

I trying to write a script that will copy files from one folder to another based on the file name(similar). As I got Few thousands text files in a folder. But I try to find few hundreds of files out of thousands files. It's takes a lot of time to search it one by one.

`Copy` seem like a good idea to use in this and then use for to loop through the list of files that I try to find out of thousands. But `Copy` need a specified name. The problem is I only have part of the file name.

Example of list of files(Content of the text file):

`ABCDEF-A01`

`ADEWSD-B03`

`ABDDER-C23`

Example of filename:

`GGI_1409506_ABCDEF-A01.txt`,`GGI_ADEWSD-B03.txt`,`DA_ABDDER-C23_12304.txt`

I only got the `ABCDEF-A01` instead of the full filename.

Expected result:

Able to search through the folder and copy the files to another location that matched according the list of files (one text files).

Anything that you can share? Info/ans/related posts? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this running on Windows? Is a solution using powershell ok?

Comment: @RobertKelly yes is Windows. Powershell is ok. As i got basic knowledge on shell too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in perl . When running the program pass the arguments for Source Directory path and Destination Directory path along with the list of filename that need to be searched. If destination directory doesn't exist it will create a folder automatically through the program as shown below :

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
my $source = $ARGV[0];
my $destination = $ARGV[1];
my $listFiles = $ARGV[2];

if(-f $destination)
 {
      print "Already unknown extension of file exists with the same name of directory. So rename the file and run the program";
      exit 0;
    }

if(-d "$destination")
 {
      print "Directory where files need to be copied: $destination\n";
    }
else    
 {
      print "No Directory found and hence created the directory $destination\n";
      mkdir("$destination");
      }

opendir DIR, $source or die "cant open dir";
my @files = grep /(.*?)(\.txt)$/,(readdir DIR);
open my $fh, '<', "$listFiles" or die "Cannot open the file names to search $listFiles - $!";
open my $out,'>', "$ARGV[1]\\NoMatch.txt" or die "Cannot write to the file NoMatch.txt - $!";
my @listFileNames = <$fh>;
my @listFiles = ();
foreach my $InputFiles (@files)
 {
      chomp($InputFiles);
    foreach my $list(@listFileNames)
    {  
    chomp($list);   
     if($InputFiles =~ /$list/isg)
      { 
      print "Files : $InputFiles copying\t";
      copy("$InputFiles","$destination");
      print "Files : $InputFiles copied\n";
      push(@listFiles,$list);     
          }
        }  
      }

my %seen = ();
my $count = 0;
foreach my $list (@listFiles)
 {
     $seen{lc($list)} = 1;
     #print $list . "\n";
      }

foreach my $listnames (@listFileNames)
 {

     if($seen{lc($listnames)})
       {
        }
     else
      {
        if($count ==0)
        {
         print "\nFilenames that did not match the text files are present in the destination folder : NoMatch.txt file " . "\n";
            }
         print $out "$listnames\n";
         $count++;
        }   
    }
close($out);      
close($fh);       
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: then which part of the code will read the `list of files` which contains all the similar filename?

Comment: You have provided us the pattern of filenames that need to be copied into destination folder. So what you mean by similar filename ? Can you be specific by providing the input and expected output ?

Comment: Here all the list of files which are similar pattern of text files provided by you are taken into an array @files  and these files are copied into the destination directory.

Comment: Oh, you are copying similar pattern of the text files. But I want to copy Similar filename, which mean the `ABCDEF-A01` is matched with the GGI_1409506_`ABCDEF-A01`.txt, I want to search for specific file not similar pattern files.

Comment: @thor_that_new_in_programming : Now the code has been modified and first i found all list of text files and in that again the files that are specific like 'ABCDEF-A01' filenames are copied into the destination directory. Here i have passed three arguments to the program source directory destination directory and listfile that contains all specific filenames . Now it will work fine...

Comment: Hello, you there? I try to modify the code by adding in print out those filenames that can't be found into a text file. But I failed to do so.. anything u can help here?

Comment: Do you want the filenames that are present in the listfile but which are not matched with the text files ?

Comment: yes bro, you got what I mean. That is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I modified the code. Now copy paste the code and jus run the program then it creates NoMatch.txt file in the destination folder . This file will give all the filenames that did not match with the text files

Comment: This is perfect for anyone that looking for specific files. Thanks man. This is great!

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file and put it in the source folder, with your list of files you want to copy.

```
for /f %%f in (list.txt) do robocopy c:\source d:\dest %%f
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use File::Copy;

    my $sorce_direcrtory = qq{};
    my $new_directory = "";

    opendir(my $dh, $sorce_direcrtory) || die;
    while(readdir $dh) {
        if($_ =~ /[A..Z]+\-[A..Z]\d+/){
            move("$sorce_direcrtory/$_", "$new_directory/$_");
        }
    }
    closedir $dh;
```

Comment: hmm, `$sorce_directory` what should i put here? Put my `list of files(.txt)` or the path where all the files located? Which part of the code call the `list of files(.txt)`

Comment: path to your directory